# What does COMP VALUE ZERO in COBOL mean?

Tags: cobol

There is a great explanation for COMP under the following stackoverflow link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42423487/7802354
but I still don't understand what COMP VALUE ZERO in

```
   77  ABC       PIC S9(4) COMP VALUE ZERO.
```

means. I would appreciate if someone clarifies that.

Comment: It initializes the variable to `0` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You're right, VALUE ZERO initializes to zero, but what about COMP VALUE ZERO? I can't understand the COMP usage in here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COMP` or `COMPUTATIONAL` refers to the storage representation. For most implementations, it is the same as (big-endian) `BINARY`, for some `PACKED-DECIMAL`, rarely it is the same 
storage representation as `DISPLAY`. `VALUE ZERO` means that the initial value will be +0.

It is similar to

```
short abc = 0;
```

in some other languages. However the `PIC S9(4)` limits the value to -9999 through +9999.

Comment: PIC S9(4) limits the value to -9999 through +9999 with standards-conforming options in effect.  For example, IBM Enterprise COBOL compiled with [TRUNC(BIN)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_6.2.0/com.ibm.cobol62.ent.doc/PGandLR/ui/up4060.html) will limit PIC S9(4) to -32768 through +32767.

Answer (score 0):

The way to read that line of code

```
77  ABC       PIC S9(4) COMP VALUE ZERO.
```

is

```
77               is the level
ABC              is the data item name
PIC S9(4) COMP   is the data item's 'data type'
VALUE ZERO       is what to initialize the data item to.
```

Comment: `PIC S9(4) COMP`   is not the data item's 'data type'. It is two separate clauses: `PIC S9(4)` which gives the range and precision, and `[USAGE] COMP[UTATIONAL]` which defines the storage representation type.